# Is it safe to allocate memory from with a c function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I want to create a function that will generate data of arbitrary length and return the array.  The memory for the data is to be allocated from within the array.  I know the following simple test code does the job allocating and returning the pointer, but what I don't know is if it is safe from being overwritten at some later time by another call of the this or some other function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float* CreateFloatArray(unsigned int N) {
    float *array = (float*) malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    return array;
}

int main() {
   float *a = CreateFloatArray(10);
//   free(a);
   float *b = CreateFloatArray(10);

   printf ("%d %d\n",a,b);
   return 0;
}
```

Just to be clear, this code is not my actual application, but rather a simple test.

At the end, the test code prints the address of the two blocks of allocated memory.  If I insert the `free(a)` command, between the two calls, then then address of a and b are identical; otherwise, they are sufficiently far apart.

So clearly, this simple test works in allocating distinct memory blocks, with no overlap, but I'm looking for assurance, from someone more knowledgeable, that there will NEVER be memory overlap throughout the execution of the program, no matter how many times I call the function? (Of course, with the understanding that careless malloc from within a function is a great way of leaking memory).

Comment: It's ok but it's completely useless because you can just write `float *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(*a));`, and you can then write a macro "*but I wouldn't*" like `MALLOC(type, size) malloc((size) * sizeof(type));` and then `float *a = MALLOC(float, 10);`

Comment: Yes, its safe, what is wrong is `printf ("%d %d\n",a,b);`, `a` and `b` are pointers to `float`, not `int`'s.

Comment: just remember to free it

Comment: *"careless malloc from within a function is a great way of leaking memory"*. No, it is failing to `free()` memory that results in leaks, or, losing / overwriting the pointer. Why are you comparing pointers after memory is `free()`ed?

Comment: Seems he wanted to read the addresses directly. Though to get that right use %u rather than %d, that way you get the unsigned address :)

Comment: @DAhrens the right use is `printf ("%p %p\n", (void*)a, (void*)b);`

Comment: Hah! I have been using a limited set of symbols on embedded operating systems for too long. I completely forgot the %p. Not every implementation has it.

Comment: There _should_ never be overlapping virtual memory returned by malloc() if the C library and OS are functioning properly. Of course if you free the memory, it is not surprising for it to be reallocated right away when you call malloc() again. Don't forget to check the return value from malloc() before using it, and free the memory when you are done. Also, when returning variable length arrays, you will need to either save the length or use an end marker to prevent access past the end of the array.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is safe to allocate dynamic memory and return the pointer to the caller function. As the dynamic memory allocator APIs [`malloc()` and family] get memory from a global heap "object", so calls even in different places won't allocate the same memory or overlap, since they're all coordinating using the global heap "object". So, until and unless you're `free()`ing the memory, that memory won't be allocated again by any other call to `malloc()`/`calloc()`.

That said, two more things to mention.

1. No need to cast the return value of `malloc()`.
2. Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Also, `printf ("%d %d\n",a,b);` is wrong. You need to use the `%p` format specifier to print the pointer (memory address).

<sup># Thanks to Mr. Mooing Duck for the comments.</sup>

Comment: I think the key thing to mention is that `malloc` gets memory from a global heap "object", so calls even in different places won't allocate the same memory or overlap, since they're all coordinating using the global heap "object".

Comment: And by global, he means operating system.

Comment: @DAhrens: Sometimes, but most of the time no.  Visual Studio and G++ and Clang all implement global heaps in the C runtime, which is easily evident because when you `delete/free` memory, that memory is rarely returned to the OS.

Comment: So they ask for a bunch of space at runtime, then keep allocating that particular region until they run out. However, that is just another layer on top of the operating system layer I referred to.

Comment: "coordinating _using_ the global heap" - note: allocating memory and using memory are not always the same.